Show how to approximate the likelihood of a Stochastic Volatility model with Gaussian AR(1) log-volatility and Gaussian errors
hi i am very new to SVM and are asked the following question:
$\textbf{(i) Show how to approximate the likelihood of a Stochastic Volatility model with Gaussian AR(1) log-volatility and Gaussian errors. Assume that the error terms in the measurement and transition equations are independent. }$
$\textbf{Stochastic Volatility model}$
$$\begin{aligned}
    y_t &= \beta \exp \left(\frac{h_t}{2}\right)\epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,1) \\
    h_{t+1}&= \phi h_t + \sigma \eta_t,\quad \eta_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)
\end{aligned}$$
$y_t|h_t \sim N(0,\beta^2 \exp(h_t))$ and $h_t|h_{t-1}\sim N(\phi h_{t-1},\sigma^2)$.
The likelihood is given by:
$$p(y_{1:T})=\int \dots \int p(y_{1:T},h_{1:T})d h_{1:T}$$
however, in this case
$$p(y_{1:T},h_{1:T})=p(h_1)p(y_1|h_1)\prod_{t=2}^T p (h_t|h_{t-1},y_{t-1})p(y_t|h_t)$$
and then you need to find $h_t|h_{t-1},y_{t-1}$. $\textbf{how do i continue from here?}$
and the question
$\textbf{(ii) How do things change if the error terms were correlated instead of being independent?}$
Thanks in advance
